How Do i get the callback adress and website needed for read/write keys with a tweetinvi desktop application?
I have been working on a project to post to twitter from a C# desktop application, and have been using the TweetInvi Library to handle the api calls but to make an api key that has access to read/write permissions on the twitter developers site I need a callback and website address, how do I obtain these for a desktop application?
I have tried using the base accessible api key and secret from the twitter for developers website but that only gave read permissions, does anyone know how to get read/write permissions without a website address?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
